# Thymeleaf can't display username and role of user

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

i can't display on my index page the role and username of authenticated user. I'm using thymeleaf. All role users saved inMemory. I'm writting and web app using spring+mvc

I add the dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
<artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
<version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
```

this is my index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<head>
    <title>Submission result</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>login ok: welcome </h1>

  <hr>
<p>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"> 
    User: <sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
    <br><br>
    Role(s): <sec:authentication property="principal.authorities" />
    </div>
</p>
```

I also thy tho use :

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('_USER')"> or is.Authorized(), but I dont diplay nothin.
```

This is my Security config class:

```
 public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    UserBuilder user=User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(user.username("user").password("user").roles("USER"))
    .withUser(user.username("try").password("try").roles("MANAGER", "USER"))
    .withUser(user.username("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "MANAGER", "ADMIN"));
    
    
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login/log").loginProcessingUrl("/login/control/").permitAll()
    .failureUrl("/client/add")//.permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().permitAll();
```

I also read many questions on stackoverlofw, but I don't find the solution. I also read the guide on officiale Thymeleaf site.

Why I can't display : "Role: user", "Username: user"?

In log I haven't errors or warning, and login works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML in the example is invalid (`<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities" />`).

I believe the syntax you are looking for is:

```html
User: <span sec:authentication="name"></span>
Role(s): <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>
```

This is described in the Thymeleaf with Spring Security [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found this code: `th:inline="text">Welcome [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]`
It's works for dispaly username, but I don't know this kind of annotation.